# How to retain millisecond information while using mktime in awk?

Tags: date, awk, strftime, mktime

I have a date string of the format 2012-12-20T01:16:02.05 and i want to convert to the format  2011-12-20-01.16.02.050000

Currently i am doing it as follows

```
format = "%F-%H.%M.%S.%N"
split(stringinput,input,"T"); 
split(input[1],date,"-")
split(input[2],time,":")

 return strftime(format,mktime(date[1] " " date[2] " " date[3] " " time[1] " " time[2] " " time[3] " " time[4]));
```

But i am losing the microsecond information or the millisecond information. How can i get that. It is returning 2011-12-20-01.16.02.%N

Also any suggestions to make the string parsing more generic. Currently it support only one format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to treat the millisecond data separately. Also, use `gensub()` to format your string information. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {

    string = "2012-12-20T01:16:02.05"

    groups = "^(....)-(..)-(..).(..):(..):(..).*"
    format = "\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5 \\6"

    datespec = gensub(groups, format, "", string)
    timestamp = mktime(datespec)


    newstring = strftime("%F-%H.%M.%S", timestamp)

    sub(/.*\./,"",string)

    printf "%s.%s0000\n", newstring, string
}
```

Results:

```
2012-12-20-01.16.02.050000
```

---

***EDIT:***

```
BEGIN {

    string = "2011-01-10T14:45:13.815-05:00"

    groups = "^(....)-(..)-(..).(..):(..):(..).*"
    format = "\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5 \\6"

    datespec = gensub(groups, format, "", string)
    timestamp = mktime(datespec)


    sub(/.*\./,"",string)

    offset = substr(string,4)

    split(offset,array,":")

    seconds = (array[1] * 60 * 60) + (array[2] * 60)

    newstring = strftime("%F-%H.%M.%S", timestamp - seconds, 1)

    printf "%s.%s00\n", newstring, substr(string,0,3)
}
```

Results:

```
2011-01-10-09.45.13.81500
```

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks it works. But will you be able to suggest me how can i make it generic to handle input in any format.

Comment: @PriyaRanjan: In _any_ format? That would be difficult. You could probably test a couple of different regexps using a loop. Then `break` the loop if `mktime()` doesn't return `-1`. If you list a few different datetime formats perhaps I could show you how exactly.

Comment: I have gone through the list and it seems that the formats that i have are of the above format with the addition of time zone information.

Comment: @PriyaRanjan: Would you be able to paste that data into your question? Expected output would be very helpful too.

Comment: I have gone through the list and it seems that the formats that i have are of the above format with the addition of time zone information like 2011-01-10T14:45:13.815-05:00 . Here the timezone is UTC-05:00  .  Can you please suggest me how to handle this.  I read through the mktime specification and it appears that it does not handle timezones .

Comment: In the above case expected would be 2011-01-10-09.45.13.815

Comment: @PriyaRanjan: I've added update. You'll need to calculate out the timezone difference in seconds and do the addition/subtraction from the timestamp. If you hadn't of shown me your results, I would have let `newstring` use `timestamp + seconds`, because `seconds` is already negative. My results would have been: `2011-01-09-23.45.13.81500`. Are you sure your expected result is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using mktime()? The change you describe is just a text change:

```
$ echo "2012-12-20T01:16:02.05" | awk '{sub(/T/,"-"); gsub(/:/,"."); print $0 "0000"}'
2012-12-20-01.16.02.050000
```

I'm assuming it was just a typo when you changed 2012 to 2011 in your output.

Answer (score 0):

Because I wanted my GNU date precision to match with awk, I had to do it in the following:

```
x='2019-05-30 14:09:20.074'
echo $x | awk '{split($1,a,"-");;split($2,b,".");split(b[1],c,":");s=a[1]" "a[2]" "a[3]" "c[1]" "c[2]" "c[3];tt=mktime(s);print tt b[2] "000000"}'
1559196560074000000

date --date=$x +'%s%N'
1559196560074000000
```

Now, that I am able to bring these two into agreement, I am now able to do comparison logic inside awk.